# Exponential of the integral of a matrix - what is wrong with this calculation/statement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponentiation

I'm going through a book we're using in our intermediate differential equations course, and this is one of the problems that are contained in it. Note that this question is not tagged as homework, because it's not, and I'm actually just trying to solve some of the problems on my own. So I guess I'll jump right into it.

**Statement:**
What is wrong with the following calculation?

$\frac{d}{dt}[exp\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds]=A(t)*[exp\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds],$

so that $exp\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds$ is a fundamental matrix of **y'** = A(t)**y** for an arbitrary continuous matrix A(t).

**My thoughts:**
I can't really think of anything other than perhaps that if A(t) is an arbitrary continuous matrix, then $exp[\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds$] need not be invertible, i.e. the solutions (columns) contained within this proposed fundamental matrix need not be linearly independent, thereby contradicting the fundamental matrix assertion. Is that all there is to it? Because I went through the calculation itself, and the equality seems perfectly legit to me.

**Further thoughts:** Let $J=\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds.$ Then $exp(J)=I+J+\frac{J^{2}}{2!}+...,$ so that by the chain rule:

$\frac{d}{dt}exp(J)=A(t)+JA(t)+\frac{J^{2}}{2!}A(t)+...\neq A(t)+A(t)J+A(t)\frac{J^{2}}{2!}+...=A(t)exp(J),$

unless $A(t)$ and $exp(J)$ commute.

Is this reasoning correct and is this why the calculation fails?

Comment: Question bodies should be self-contained; I couldn't figure out what the actual problem was until I reread the title. I think the sentence "What is wrong with this calculation/statement?" should appear somewhere in the body of the question rather than the title. // Also, use `\exp` instead of `exp` to get something that looks like an operator name and not the product of three variables $e$, $x$, and $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that A is a function of s, and therefore need not have the same value for all s. In particular, A(s) and A(s') need not commute. Try redoing your calculation using the limit definition of the derivative and being careful about your assumptions of what commutes. It may be helpful to look up the Zassenhaus formula, which is one way to evaluate the left hand side of your equation, or the Dyson series, which gives the correct form of the solution for your associated differential equation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I namely don't quite get it. I know A is a function of t (or s in the integral), but when you differentiate $exp\int^{t}_{t_0}A(s)ds$, you get the RHS exactly by the fundamental theorem of calculus. I've also written it out using the definition of matrix exponentiation $e^{A}=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+...$, and it seems to work. So any further input would be greatly appreciated. And where do you see a problem with commuting?

Comment: To get the right hand side from the left, you are implicitly using the chain rule in addition to the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Yes, I know, I forgot to mention that. Why would that be wrong, though?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to be so cryptic. Had to switch devices because typing math on a Kindle is a nightmare. The derivative of the left hand side is $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \exp(\int_0^t ds A(s)+\delta A(t))-\exp(\int_0^t ds A(s))$, but $A(t)$ need not commute with $\int_0^t ds A(s)$, so the expansion of the first exponential in a Taylor series is not so simple. Your equation would hold true if these two quantities commute.

Comment: If you ever need a closed form for the derivative, you can use the expansion formula $\exp(X+Y)\approx\exp(X)+\exp(X)\int_0^1 du\exp(-Xu)Y\exp(Xu)+\mathcal{O}(Y^2)$ in small Y in the above limit form of the derivative.

Comment: I made an edit to my original post (the further thoughts section), so could you please take a look and tell me whether this is what you meant and/or whether my reasoning is correct, and that's why the calculation would fail?

Comment: The derivative of $J^3$ is not $3J^2A$ but rather is $J^2A+JAJ+AJ^2$. Other terms are similar.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, you _do_ get that if you write it out as $JJJ$ rather than $J^{3}$ and then apply the chain rule. But why did the chain rule with the second expression give me a different answer? What did I do wrong?

Comment: The chain rule doesn't apply the same way to matrices. You should check everything with the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that in light of the fact that $J^{n}$ is just shorthand for $JJ...JJ$ n-times and that the chain rule in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ hinges on commutativity, I can't just apply it like I did above.